# logback adding different patterns conditionally for custom message converter

Tags: logback, masking

I am using logback to log Json messages coming from different Rest endpoints within the same module. My attempt is to log all request responses to one file. The problem is some endpoints require masking of sensitive data, and others does not.
My attempt was creating custom MessageConverter, and passing different options at logback configuration file.

```
<configuration>
<conversionRule conversionWord="mask" converterClass="com.me.filter.MessageCompositeConverter" />
```

I have an appender, which has a pattern also using the conversionWord

```
<appender name="AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        </encoder>
    <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %mask(%m){ssn, email}%n</pattern>          
        </encoder>
</appender>
```

Here I am only providing two options ssn, email, but I have like 9 such options or keys that I used to later for masking.

```
 MessageCompositeConverter extends CompositeConverter<ILoggingEvent> {
    private MaskUtil maskUtil;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        maskUtil = new MaskingUtils();
        maskUtil.init(getOptionList());//ssn and email options
        super.start();
    }

    
    @Override
    protected String transform(ILoggingEvent event, String in) {
        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(in);
                //mask method takes the messages, and uses the options set at the start() method
               // and does a switch to calls different masking methods for different sensitive data
        maskUtil.mask(msg);
        return maskUtil.getMessageBuilder().toString();
    }
```

switch statement is similar as below

```
public String mask(String message )
....
for (int i = 0, i < options.size();i++
     switch(options.get(i)
       case "email"
          maskEmail
         break;
       case "ssn":
         maskSSN
         .....
```

With current implementation above switch is running for every message being logged

The problem is some endpoints does not have sensitive data to be masked. In such cases I am running my masking logic, even when it is not needed.
Is there a way to add different patterns conditionally at logback xml file, if possible?

```
Example if message.contains("serviceid_1") 
           <pattern>....</pattern>
           message.contains("serviceid_2")
           <pattern>....</pattern>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Logback doesn't support conditional patterns directly within its XML configuration file.**

you could implement your conditional logic within the CompositeConverter's transform method to decide which types of masking need to be applied based on the message content.

If the message doesn't contain sensitive data, you can bypass the masking logic.

```
   @Override
    protected String transform(ILoggingEvent event, String in) {
        if (in.contains("serviceid_1")) {
            // apply masking for serviceid_1
            maskUtil.mask(in, "ssn");
        } else if (in.contains("serviceid_2")) {
            // apply masking for serviceid_2
            maskUtil.mask(in, "email");
        } else {
            // no masking required
            return in;
        }
        return maskUtil.getMessageBuilder().toString();
    }
```

Comment: the code you provided that is the sort of approach I have currently, and I am looking more at configuration file, if possible. What about having more than one appenders some sort of parent child, and each child appender define their own pattern. I am giving you point as your answer shows one possible approach